# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis?

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

I keep getting the following error when trying to execute the following WHERE condition but can't quite figure out what the actual problem is... any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
WHERE ((CUSTOMER.CREATE_DATE >= TO_DATE($$EXTRACT_DT,'YYYYMMDD')) OR
(CUSTOMER.UPDATE_DATE >= TO_DATE($$EXTRACT_DT,'YYYYMMDD')))
```

NOTE:
Would like to add that when I remove the WHERE condition, the query executes without any issues.

Comment: The parens balance, the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: So what is `$$EXTRACT_DATE`? Some kind of parameter notation?

Comment: @APC Yes, that's an Informatica parameter notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parens balance -- 5 `(` and 5 `)`.  I would write the code to make this obvious:

```
WHERE (CUSTOMER.CREATE_DATE >= TO_DATE($$EXTRACT_DT, 'YYYYMMDD') OR
       CUSTOMER.UPDATE_DATE >= TO_DATE($$EXTRACT_DT, 'YYYYMMDD')
      )
```

(This removes the parentheses on each clause.)

Hence, your problem would appear to be elsewhere in the query.

Comment: The rest of the query is just the SELECT CUSTOMER.(column attributes) FROM CUSTOMER. I've checked it many times, the query runs fine without the WHERE condition. Really not sure what's wrong...

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale . . . In that case, it is probably the interpretation of `$$EXTRACT_DT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE (CUSTOMER.CREATE_DATE >= TO_DATE("$$EXTRACT_DT", 'YYYYMMDD') OR
       CUSTOMER.UPDATE_DATE >= TO_DATE("$$EXTRACT_DT", 'YYYYMMDD')
      )
```

Comment: Oracle uses double quotes for object identifier names. Is Informatica going to interpret those differently before it reaches Oracle? (It seems to be doing something with them already; otherwise you'd get "ORA-00911: invalid character" from the dollar signs. Presumably it's parameter substitution.)

Comment: @AlexPoole, is right, Informatica is already interpreting the paramters without double quotes. I also thought it might've been a parameter issue, but the error reads the correct paramatized value so that rules it out. Also tried subsitting the entire WHERE condition with something simple like "WHERE CUSTOMER.INDICATOR = 'Y'" and the whole thing runs, pinpointing the issue exclusively to the posted WHERE condition. No clue what could be causing a "missing right parenthesis" issue...

Comment: @WhimsicalWhale - so if you copy and paste the values from the log into the query it runs OK? I imagine it's being seen as unquoted text and parentheses or a comma or a quote or a keyword or something within the value is causing the error. Doesn't really make sense when  it looks like you are expecting an 8-digit number, but we can't see what you really have...

Comment: @AlexPoole, I figured it out.... the paramatized value is wrong. Input values were not the right format. Thanks for the help!